# Remove one specific app indicator from top panel bar

Tags: indicator, panel

I installed once a notification app that I don't really use.  Problem is I don't even know what it's called or how to remove it. It's the mail box icon on the left in the picture.

[image]

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Have you clicked on it? Have you installed any mail applications?

Comment: I have clicked on it (left & right). It only show the notifications, no settings or about or anything. I remember it was supposed to give me system notifications, which it does (network connections etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [Recent Notifications AppIndicator](https://itsfoss.com/notifications-appindicator/). You can make sure whether it is installed by opening Terminal and running

```
apt-cache policy indicator-notifications
```

After confirmation run the following in Terminal to remove it

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-notifications
```